# git push local branch to remote branch

Tags: git, git-push

I'm going to push a local branch to a existing remote branch. The command I found is this:
git push repository_name branch_name

I'm confused with branch_name is this the name of the local branch I will push, or the name of the remote branch I will push to?

Comment: It depends what you actually run. `git push`? `git push <remote> <branch>`? Something else? Read e.g. `git push -h`.

Comment: If you do not provide the name of the branch, git will push to the "upstream" branch.... which is normally a branch with the same name of the local branch (if that is not the case, git by default complains about it).

Comment: Git, by the way, allows for weird combinations like: `git push a-remote a-local-branch:a-remote-branch`, in case you want to go wild west.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I mean git push <remote> <branch>. Sorry I didn't find that it didn't present "<remote>" and "<branch>" on my question

Answer (score 6):

The safe standard way to do this is to say

```
git push origin @
```

That means: "Push the current local branch [the branch we are on right now] to a remote branch with the same name." That is the usual thing to want to do, and is so common in my own world that I have created an alias for it.

Comment: Gives me an error.

Answer (score 5):

You can push your local branch to git using this cmd

if you dont have your local branch on remote yet:

```
git push --set-upstream origin local_branch_name
```

and if u already have your local branch on remote just need to push

```
git push origin
```

Comment: If you've already set your tracking correctly you don't need the remote, either.